# How to pass sameSite: none from Dockerized Node app running on Azure AppService?

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, https, samesite

I have several Node applications that run in Docker containers hosted on Azure AppServices.

I'm trying to figure out how to deal with the SameSite cookie issue, but to do that I need https.  At the moment, the Node/Express apps are running http inside the container, and then Azure is attaching our certificates to the AppService to run https.

We're using cookie-session with the following options:

```
app.use(
  cookieSession(
    {
      name: 'session',
      keys: [ '123456789ABCD' ],
      // Cookie Options
      maxAge:   24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,  // 24 hours
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: 'none',
      secure:   true
    }
  )
)
```

`sameSite: 'none'` and `secure: true` are new, but whenever I deploy the secure: true blows up my app, because I'm not running http inside the container, so the cookies get stripped.

I've also tried `app.set('trust proxy', 1)`, but couldn't tell that it had any impact.

Dockerfile:

```
# Create a container image for the app
FROM node:erbium-alpine

# Allow NODE_ENV to be set to different values
# depending on the image build/deployment environment
ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/app

# Copy package.json and yarn.lock into app directory
COPY ./package.json ./
COPY ./yarn.lock ./

# Install backend NPM modules
RUN yarn install

# COPY the client package and yarn files into app
COPY ./client/package.json ./client/
COPY ./client/yarn.lock ./client/

# Install client NPM modules
RUN yarn run install:client

# COPY the rest of the files into app directory
COPY ./ ./

# build the client
RUN yarn run build:client

# Expose ports for accessing the app
EXPOSE 5000 80

# Launch the Express server
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

What's a good approach given this deployment scheme?  Do I add some self signed cert into the container, or am I just missing a setting somewhere?

And then after I fix this for Azure, how do I run it in development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AppService, SSL termination happens at the network load balancers, so all HTTPS requests reach your app as unencrypted HTTP requests. But, `SameSite=None` must be `secure`i.e. the cookie is only to be sent over HTTPS. If `secure` is set to `true` and Node.js is not directly over a TLS connection like in this case, you need to set trusted proxy properly so that `X-Forwarded-*` headers are passed and cookie is set correctly. Set the following during your express app bootstrapping.

```
app.set('trust proxy', 2);
```

You mentioned you tried `app.set('trust proxy', 1)` which means it's only for 1st hop. In this case we need 2 hops to include the ingress for the container apart from the network load balancer. For details refer [this](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html).

> And then after I fix this for Azure, how do I run it in development?

If you set `app.set('trust proxy', 2);`, I believe you won't need any special treatment for local debugging.

Comment: Krishnendu, I tried setting `trust proxy` to `true`, but the application still fails to set my cookies.  Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: Can you try with `app.set('trust proxy', 2);` (second hop), then 3 and so on..(you said you tried with 1 already)

Comment: Thanks Krishnendu. `app.set('trust proxy', 2)` worked for me.

Comment: How does this not have more up votes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As @krishg pointed out, your app is running behind the Azure load-balancers which seen as a proxy.

If you are using express-sessions, you can set proxy=true in the options

```
var sessionOptions = {
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    store: MongoStore.create(MongoStoreOptions),
    saveUninitialized: true,
    rolling: true,
    proxy: true, // <- Important for Azure
    cookie: {
        maxAge: sessionCookieTime,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: 'None',
        }
    }
```

Or you can set it after creating the sessionOptions object, based on the environment.

```
if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
    sessionOptions.proxy = true;
}
```